# Segmentation fault when using copy constructor C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

Everything seems to be copying fine, but when I call `array2.print()`, it shows segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>


template <typename T>
class DynamicArray
{
private:
    const int GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;
    const int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 5;

    T *m_array;
    int m_capacity; // Capacity of the array
    int m_size; // Number of added elements

public:
    DynamicArray(std::initializer_list<T> elements)
        : m_size(elements.size()) 
        , m_capacity(elements.size() * 2)
    {
        m_array = new T[m_capacity];
        std::copy(elements.begin(), elements.end(), m_array);
    }

    DynamicArray()
        : m_size(0)
        , m_capacity(INITIAL_CAPACITY)
    {
        m_array = new T[m_capacity];
    }

    ~DynamicArray()
    {
        delete[] m_array;
    }

    DynamicArray(const DynamicArray& other)
        : GROWTH_FACTOR(other.GROWTH_FACTOR)
        , INITIAL_CAPACITY(other.INITIAL_CAPACITY)
        , m_capacity(other.m_capacity)
        , m_size(other.m_size)
    {
        T *m_array = new T[m_capacity];
        std::copy(other.m_array, other.m_array + m_size, m_array);
    }

    int size()
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    int capacity()
    {
        return m_capacity;
    }
    
    void resize()
    {
        int new_capacity = m_capacity *  GROWTH_FACTOR;
        m_capacity = new_capacity;
        T *temp = new T[new_capacity];
        std::copy(m_array, m_array + m_capacity, temp);
        delete[] m_array;
        m_array = temp;
    }

    void deleteAt(int pos) 
    {
        for (int i = pos; i < m_size - 1; i++)
        {
            (*this)[i] = (*this)[i + 1];
        }

        m_size--;
    }

    void insertAt(T value, int pos)
    {
        if (m_capacity == m_size)
        {
            resize();
        }

        for (int i = m_size - 1; i >= pos; i--)
        {
            (*this)[i + 1] = (*this)[i];
        }

        m_size++;
        (*this)[pos] = value;
    }

    void append(T value)
    {
        insertAt(value, m_size);
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        {
            std::cout << (*this)[i] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    T& operator[](int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > m_size - 1)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Index out of range!");
        }

        return m_array[index];
    }
    

};

int main()
{
    DynamicArray<int> array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    DynamicArray<int> array2 = array;
    array2.print(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More uncalled for advice. I would make `GROWTH_FACTOR` and `INITIAL_CAPACITY` static constants, i.e. `static const int GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;`. That way they aren't part of any particular array object. So they don't have to be copied from object to object. They effectively become global constants but with visibility restricted to the DynamicArray class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is here

```
T *m_array = new T[m_capacity];
```

It should be

```
m_array = new T[m_capacity];
```

By declaring a new variable called `m_array` you hid the class member variable that you wanted to assign to. The technical name for this is *shadowing*, a good compiler would warn you about this.

Comment: a Good compiler should warn you about this?? On my compiler it says: error: redeclaration of m_array??

Comment: @YunfeiChen Your compiler is broken then, it''s perfectly legal to shadow one declaration with another at an inner scope.

Answer (score 0):

You redeclare m_array in the cctor, which shadows the class member.